# C# Send XmlDocument to Xml-RPC Server API

Tags: c#, xml, xml-rpc

I am answering my own question because I had problems to find a solution for this. Maybe it will help someone. I had a request to send a XML to an Https API that only accepts XML-RPC request.

This article helped me to understand XML-RPC: http://codinghints.blogspot.co.at/2010/03/xml-rpc-calls-with-c.html

And this is how I solved it:

**Using**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
```

**1. My method to create a XmlDocument**

(Only needed if there is not already a XmlDocument)

```
public static XmlDocument CreateXmlDocument(string number, string email)
{
    #region root Node
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("methodCall");
    xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
    #endregion

    #region XML Node Method name
    XmlNode methodNameNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("methodName");
    methodNameNode.InnerText = "customer.send";
    rootNode.AppendChild(methodNameNode);
    #endregion

    #region XML Parameters
    XmlNode paramsNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("params");

    #region Setting Number
    XmlNode paramElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("param");
    XmlNode valueAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateElement("value");
    XmlNode stringAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateElement("string");
    stringAttribute.InnerText = number;
    valueAttribute.AppendChild(stringAttribute);
    paramElement.AppendChild(valueAttribute);
    #endregion

    #region Setting Email
    XmlNode paramElement2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("param");
    XmlNode valueAttribute2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("value");
    XmlNode stringAttribute2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("string");
    stringAttribute2.InnerText = email;
    valueAttribute2.AppendChild(stringAttribute2);
    paramElement2.AppendChild(valueAttribute2);
    #endregion

    #region Setting validation
    XmlNode paramElement3 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("param");
    XmlNode valueAttribute3 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("value");
    XmlNode stringAttribute3 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("i4");
    stringAttribute3.InnerText = "5";
    valueAttribute3.AppendChild(stringAttribute3);
    paramElement3.AppendChild(valueAttribute3);
    #endregion

    #region Adding Number, Email and validation to paramsNode
    paramsNode.AppendChild(paramElement);
    paramsNode.AppendChild(paramElement2);
    paramsNode.AppendChild(paramElement3);
    rootNode.AppendChild(paramsNode);
    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region Setting encoding to UTF8
    XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
    xmlDeclaration.Encoding = "UTF-8";
    //xmlDec.Standalone = "yes";
    XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);
    #endregion

    return xmlDoc;

}
```

This will generate a XML like this

[image]

**2. Use the method and convert the XmlDocument to send it to the API**

```
// Create a new XML document with the give values
XmlDocument xmlRequest = CreateXmlDocument(number, email);

// Convert the Xml to a byte array for the HTTPS
byte[] requestData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlRequest.InnerXml.ToString());

// Define the request
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("UrlToHttpsApi");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; }; //only needed to allow self-signed certificates. If possible don't use this

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    requestStream.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);

string result = null;

// Send XML to the API
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

**3. Work with the result (just as example)**

```
// Serialize the result as XML
XmlDocument xmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
xmlResponse.LoadXml(result);
```

Maybe it's not the best solution. But it does the job like it should.